# KnockoutJS How to observe object property?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to change visible property after change checkbox state.

My code (not work):

JS:

```
self.selectedItem = ko.observable({name:'myName', is_root: true})
```

HTML:

```
<span data-bind="visible:selectedItem().is_root">element is root!</span>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectedItem().is_root">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `is_root` has to be `ko.observable(true)`. Any property you want to be "dynamic" should be `observable`.

Answer (score 0):

Object has to be observable:

```
var Item = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable('');
    self.is_root = ko.observable(true);

    if (data != null) {
        self.name(data.name);
        self.is_root(data.is_root);
    }
}
```

then you would call:

```
self.selectedItem = ko.observable(new Item({name:'myName', is_root: true}));
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="with: selectedItem">
    <span data-bind="visible: is_root">element is root!</span>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: is_root">
</div>
```